# HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. `json_build_object`

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgis

I have a PostgreSQL database named `mypsqldb` with a table called `mypostgistable`. It's on a Linode-hosted Ubuntu 14.04 image. I ran these commands from the terminal.

```
sudo su - postgres
psql
\c mypsqldb
create extension postgis;
SELECT json_build_object('type','Feature','geometry',ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::json)  FROM mypostgistable;
```

I got this error: `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

But when I run the same query on my desktop computer, which runs Debian 9, I get no error and the query successfully executes.

I have already run `sudo apt-get install && sudo apt-get upgrade`, as well as `sudo apt-get install postgresql postgis*` on both my desktop and Linode server.

Here's the outputs for each machine when I run `SELECT version();`.

Linode/Ubuntu 14.04: `PostgreSQL 9.3.22 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4, 64-bit`.

Desktop/Debian 9: `PostgreSQL 9.6.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit`

Why does the query fail on the Linode server?

Answer (score 1):

json_build_object first occured in PostgreSQL 9.4.

Comment: Can I update my Postgres version on the Ubuntu instance?

Comment: Sure - just use PostgreSQL/Ubuntu repository, not Ubuntu itself.